# Please have <head> as the first element in your document

Tags: angular

I just upgraded to Angular 5 from version 4 and I'm receiving this error in the console:

```
Error: Please have <head> as the first element in your document
    at ServerTransferState.inject (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:183316:23)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:170489:27)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:17319:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:17266:22)
    at Subscriber._next (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:17206:26)
    at Subscriber.next (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:17170:18)
    at FirstSubscriber._emitFinal (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:117823:25)
    at FirstSubscriber._emit (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:117806:14)
    at FirstSubscriber._next (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:117785:18)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/michaelwilson/Code/project/dist/server.js:17170:18)
```

I'm using Angular Universal, my `index.html` does have head as the first element in the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   ...
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The problem is specific to your project https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1WnVzH5WejYJ:https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/custom-webpack/src/modules/transfer-state/server-transfer-state.ts+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru#L28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @estus, this was a problem specific with my project (it was using [universal-starter](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1WnVzH5WejYJ:https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/custom-webpack/src/modules/transfer-state/server-transfer-state.ts+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru#L28) which threw an error when:

```
const head = document.head;

if (head.name !== 'head') {
  throw new Error('Please have <head> as the first element in your document');
}
```

All I had to do is change it to this:

```
const head = document.head;

if (head.tagName !== 'HEAD') {
  throw new Error('Please have <head> as the first element in your document');
}
```

And the error disappeared :)